# Что можно использовать spring boot для управления сессией?

Tags: spring-boot

Что посоветуете использовать для создания сессии в spring-boot для  написания небольшого теста, с вариантами и ответа и тд....??

Comment: Ваш вопрос не понятен. Spring Boot не имеет ни сессий, ни фабрик сессий - это своего рода оболочка (но удобная) для других модулей Spring и т.д.. И какую сессию хотите создать: сессия работы с базой данных - Spring JPA, сессия работы веб-клиента - Spring Web + Spring Mvc. Думаю в других модулях под этот термин так же найдутся какие либо объекты. Сделайте вопрос более корректным.

Comment: @АлександрСавостьянов - давайте я попробую описать, что надо: нужно написать тестик, чтобы в из 100 вопросиков выбиралось 20-30 (это я знаю как написать) и после прохождения показывала бы результаты. Я это собирался разделить на 2 части: 1. Когда сервер отправляет все вопросы в браузер и он по 1 задает пользователю вопросы собирался держать в сесси локальной в браузере. 2. Это проверка ответов и отправить обратно. И вот как сохранять на сервере на сервере отправленные вопросы именно этому пользователю не знаю